# C# live video streaming and PHP client

Tags: c#, php, video-streaming, webclient

I was wondering if it's possible to  create an application in C# to streaming video to a php client. Someone out there have already try such thing or can indicate where to find resources to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just take the reference of this link. You will get the idea to resolve your problem.

[UDP Streaming transfer from C# application to PHP webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330250/udp-streaming-transfer-from-c-application-to-php-webpage)

Comment: Except the post does not deal with PHP .... the client seems to be FLASH ;) not Php ;)

Comment: Okay, My interpretation is not so fine. Thnx +1 For this

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by *a PHP client*?

Last time I checked, PHP was a PURE server side technology, and the "client" is a web browser that does not care about what the server uses but interprets the PHP output which are essentially strings in HTML and JavaScript.

So, what you want to achieve having a video decoded **on the server**? Send them as JPG images to the client?

Comment: I mean php page :)! But yes, i do want a video decoder into a php page!