# how to implement video webcast on the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming

we have a video file which we have to "webcast" on the website (ASP.NET MVC 4 C#) to about 1000 users. I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I'm looking for answers to the following questions:

1. How webcasts are implemented in general? what are keywords I should be googling for?
2. How to synchronize video streams sent to different users?
3. How much computing power do I need for 1000 users? Need a rough answer of course. One server, or tens of servers.

any links, blog articles etc would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Wait, you have a *video file* that you want to show to 1k users? You just serve the video, you don't need no cpu power for that. I would worry more about the traffic.

Comment: @Steve   yes - but that should not be like a YouTube video - all those 1000 users should see it at the same time, no way to rewind or something. Think about it as a "prerecorded" webcast

Comment: There are a bunch of live streaming services. Check out http://www.justin.tv/ for one. Also http://www.ustream.tv/

Comment: @Papa it has to be part of the website we are developing. I.e. users have to log in, etc.

Comment: You can embed the video player into your site and make the vid private, I'm sure.

Comment: @Papa please read my comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In general webcasts are implemented where there is a client software that sends tcp packets of stream data to server and server represents those packets as moving pictures.
2. In theory they already should be synchronized since you don't send the full video, you only send the current packets that are then buffered and represented as moving pictures. There will always be inconstancy in milliseconds because you cannot control every users ping to server.
3. It all depends on quality of your video as well as your webserver. No one will give you straight answer, you should always profile your applications on your own and see what bests fits *your* needs.

Since you are using C# MVC it is coupled with IIS, and IIS has something they call [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media) that does exactly [what you need](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming). Definitely check it out.

Also you should check out *c# live streadming* in google, I found very interesting approach right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330250/udp-streaming-transfer-from-c-sharp-application-to-php-webpage).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a streaming media person, here are my suggestions.

1. You could do a "live" webcast or an on-demand webcast depending on your choice. Live means, if you have a video file, you could broadcast it to multiple users at once and all will see it as if watching in a TV. They cannot pause your video. Normally, only live events are being broadcasted like this, unless you have a specific reason to broadcast an existing video file as a "fake" live broadcast.
2. You could use Windows Media Server (Add the media role in Windows Server 2003/2008/2012). Configuring and starting a windows media server needs intermediate level of familiarity with the streaming process, server, firewalls, exceptions. You have a lot of configurations which you can manage in this way, and generally suggested if you are very serious about your streaming. RTSP saves a lot of bandwidth for you too.
3. You could use Flash Media Server/Wowza media Server, Real Streaming Server also inplace of Windows media server.
4. For limited number of users, you can download the free Windows media Encoder, and select your file to be streamed, and click to stream easily. This is the easiest.
5. You could use managed streaming services from few thirdparties, like Livestream, Brightcove etc to stream video files.. Once you signup with them, the will give you an FTP/web space to upload your files, and they provide a link to the file (streaming media link). This link, you could embed in any popular player (like JWPlayer or any of that kind), and embed your player in your webpage for your users to start seeing the media. This is the most easy way to set it up. Maybe you can even get a 15 day trial services from brightcove or Mogolous.

Hope this answers your question.